# Swift - Table View Custom Cell Like Notes App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Could someone tell me what the best way to create a custom editable cell like the native iOS notes app?

I want to have a list of items, and then have a blank cell that if you click on will allow you to type in something custom. Something like this, but because I've made the code that clicking on a row brings up further actions, I'd like to be able to have the "add new category" row be automatically selected if someone types something in it.

[image]

Is there a custom prototype cell, or is the best way to do that just to put a text field in the prototype cell? And how would you do that with the didSelectRowAt function?

Comment: You can have two type of cell, one for your datasource and one for the user to type in.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tabbed application template,

1. the nav buttons will be preset and positioned
2. put an input textfield on the 2nd viewcontroller/scene
3. then put a save button
4. then code the action for it as below:

   ```
   @IBAction func saveBtn(_ sender: Any) {    
       let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object( forKey: "items") 

       var items: [String]

       if let tempItems = itemsObject as? [String]{    
           items = tempItems       
           items.append(textField.text!)   
       } else {
           items = [textField.text!]
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: *`var items: [String]  // initialize items`* this is not initializing items. That is just a declaration.

Comment: Fixed it, @vikingosegundo